# Xamarin Forms Embeded resource image as background for ContentPage in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying the Xamarin Forms for the first time so this may be a badly written question, pardon me please if so.

I have a image as a Embeded resource:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPPo7.png)
Can i use that image as BackgroundImage in XAML, for the ContentPage? How

Thank you all in advance.

UPDATE, as proposed here:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/#Embedded_Images:

1. i added the custom xaml markup extension to main page cs:

> ```
> [Xamarin.Forms.ContentProperty("Source")]
> public class ImageResourceExtension : Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.IMarkupExtension
> {
>     public string Source { get; set; }
>
>     public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
>     {
>         if (Source == null)
>         {
>             return null;
>         }
>         // Do your translation lookup here, using whatever method you require
>         var imageSource = Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource.FromResource(Source);
>
>         return imageSource;
>     }
> }
> ```

2. I can now use the image like this:

> ```
>   <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
>     <!-- use a custom Markup Extension -->
>     <Image Source="{local:ImageResource App2.images.back_01.png}" />
>   </StackLayout>
> ```

3. Still the original question i am unable to answer, how to make it background in

> ```
> <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
>              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
>              xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App2;assembly=App2"
>              x:Class="App2.MainPage"
>              BackgroundImage="">
> ```

Comment: I think you need to say `local:ImageResourceExtension` instead of `local:ImageResource` in XAML code

Comment: As I observed, **BackgroundImage** works only for iOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that making the image Embedded resource *only* in portable, works for all image usages *except* BackgroundImage.
To be used for BackgroundImage the image has to be *also* embedded in the per platform resources (correct per platform Build Action must be selected).
Then, for BackgroundImage, it can be refereed to like this: "folder_name/file_name.png"
So, it must be done several times instead once (as opposed to *other* image usages).
The above has worked for me as a solution. 
If someone know how to do this without redundant actions, please do post.

Answer (score -2):

Put images to folder:

for `Android` into `Resources/drawable`

for `iOS` into `Resources`

And then try

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App2;assembly=App2"
             x:Class="App2.MainPage"
             BackgroundImage="back01.png">
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but its almost the same as the solution below. The whole point was to use the image _only_ as a embedded resource within the portable part and not per platform, which, for the background image seems not possible.